# Uno entre catorce mil – ¡Enhorabuena Charlie por llegar a 50 K!

Tags: discusión, usuarios

Más de catorce mil usuarios registrados.

Más de quinientos usuarios en el *ranking* de reputación.

Menos de una decena de ellos por encima de diez mil puntos.

Pero solo UNO ha sido el primero en superar la barrera de CINCUENTA MIL puntos de reputación.

**¡Enhorabuena, [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie)!**

En vista de tamaño acontecimiento, y aprovechando también que hoy cumples años, la comunidad se ha reunido en secreto estos últimos días para prepararte un regalo.

El regalo lo verás en un rato, cuando te pasemos las credenciales de un email donde está "guardado".

Con este regalo queremos agradecerte lo mucho y tan bien que has contribuido a la comunidad, a que el español sea un idioma más cercano y amable, curioso y lleno de recovecos donde meterse y aprender constantemente.

¡Esperamos que lo disfrutes! (Y que no abuses del regalo para llegar a 100 K demasiado rápido muajuajua)

Comment: Has llegado a los 50K el primero y el segundo, el siguiente tendrá que conformarse con una triste medalla de bronce. Enhorabuena y que sigas dando vidilla a este sitio con tus preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: Enhorabuena Charlie. Bien merecido es este regalo. La reputación es una medida de lo mucho que la comunidad confía en un usuario, pero este obsequio demuestra aún más lo espléndido de todas tus contribuciones y lo mucho que la comunidad valora tus aportaciones. No queremos solo premiarte por llegar el primero a los 50K, si no agradecerte la forma en la que lo has hecho: preguntas muy interesantes, respuestas geniales e increíblemente bien documentadas (a veces a preguntas que ya considerábamos "irresolubles"), trato cortés a todos los usuarios, usuario modelo y un ejemplo a seguir. **Gracias**

Comment: @Diego leñe, cuando yo ya pensaba que iba a pasar una tarde tranquila llegas tú y hale, otra vez con la lagrimita... :´-)

Comment: @blonfu que conste que lo de llegar primero y segundo no ha sido culpa mía, que menudo susto nos dimos todos ese día... Anda, me ha rimado y todo...

Comment: @Charlie es cojonudo tenerte por aquí, compartiendo inquietudes y ayudando a que todos aprendamos y nos enfrasquemos en este juego de la lengua tan bonito que hemos encontrado en este sitio. ¡Enhorabuena! ¡Un abrazo gigante!

Comment: Qué bárbaro, Charlie, ¡felicidades!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Habéis conseguido que se me escape la lagrimita en pleno trabajo, menos mal que para esas cosas soy comedido y consigo disimularlo, pero que sepáis que todavía tengo la piel de gallina y me tiembla todo.

Pocas veces me he sentido tan querido y aceptado como me siento aquí (por supuesto sin contar a mi familia, claro). No sabéis la ilusión que me ha hecho el regalo, pienso darle un buen uso y montar respuestas lo más alucinantes que pueda, aunque ahora me llevará un tiempo aprender a usar toda la nueva información disponible. Sabed que llegar a los 50K ha sido un placer al lado de gente como vosotros.

Este será un día que recordaré durante mucho tiempo. ¡Muchísimas gracias a todos los que habéis participado! ¡Al turrón!

Comment: Sin duda le darás un buen uso al regalo, que a la vez es un regalo para todos ya que revertirá en el sitio en forma de respuestas bien documentadas. Para nosotros es también un placer contar contigo, no ya como usuario excepcional, que también (por supuesto), sino como persona. ¡A disfrutarlo!

Comment: @walen acabo de entender lo de , yo pensando "oreja, ok, oreja, ok, oreja, ok, ¿qué querrá decir con eso?", y ahora por fin he entendido lo de los tirones de orejas. Esto de los jeroglíficos con emojis no es lo mío, tres horas he tardado... :-D

Answer (score 3):

Al césar lo que es del césar. Ya que estamos, quiero dar las gracias a dos usuarios en especial por sus destacadas contribuciones para hacer realidad este regalo/homenaje:

## Fedorqui, mil gracias

Por idear y promover este regalo para Charlie.

## Walen, mil gracias

Por ocuparte de múltiples trámites y gestiones para hacer posible este regalo a Charlie.

Comment: gracias por mencionarme, si bien es importante destacar que fue walen quien lo empezó todo! [_Gracias walen, contigo empezó todo_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMBgtoluiIo) :P Yo utilicé los superpoderes de moderador para facilitar la conexión entre los usuarios.