# Un millón de gracias

Tags: discusión

Aunque hace ya seis meses que la comunidad celebró [mi llegada a los 50 mil puntos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/12637), las sorpresas resulta que siguen llegando. No hace mucho recibí en casa un regalo por parte de Stack Exchange que, al recuperar por fin un proveedor para enviar regalos corporativos, procedió a enviarme un paquetito con un detallito, siguiendo las instrucciones de una conversación secreta que se mantuvo en su día y de la que no he sabido nada hasta hace relativamente poco.

Así pues, aprovecho la ocasión para daros de nuevo las gracias, y para adjuntaros una foto:

[image: Termo]

El regalo es un vaso térmico que mantiene caliente el líquido que le eches, en mi caso me lo traigo todos los días al trabajo cargado de té. Debo decir que su función térmica la cumple con creces, mantiene el té calentito mejor incluso que el termo que usaba antes, pero la tapa no es hermética y si no tengo cuidado voy derramando té en el camino al trabajo. :-)

Pues eso, como decía, muchas gracias a todos los que participasteis en aquel detalle, y a la comunidad en general por haberme acogido y haber aceptado mis preguntas y respuestas.

Vamos a por los 100 mil, que con el recálculo de puntos ahora lo tengo más cerca. :-)

Comment: Y no se te olvide pedir la gorra y la camiseta (creo que también te manda unas pegatinas) que te dan por se moderador.