# ¿Merece la pena tener una cuenta de Enclave RAE?

Tags: discusión, recursos

Hace casi un año [fui obsequiado por esta comunidad](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/1674) con una cuenta anual de *[Enclave RAE](https://enclave.rae.es/)*, la plataforma de pago de la RAE con multitud de herramientas lingüísticas. Así que tras todo este tiempo probándola, toca responder a la pregunta que todos se hacen (es un decir):

¿Merece la pena pagar el precio de la suscripción anual<sup>1</sup> de la plataforma *Enclave RAE*?

---

<sup>1</sup> 30 euros a día de publicación de esta pregunta.

Comment: Haciéndola algo más objetiva (sin lo de "vale la pena") bien podría esta pregunta pertenecer al sitio principal, pues da buen detalle de lo que ofrece.

Comment: @fedorqui pues mira que lo pensé, pero es que tenía mis dudas porque no es una pregunta sobre el español, sino sobre un recurso específico de la RAE, y sí, es mi opinión lo que expongo. Por estos motivos decidí ponerla aquí y darle un poco de visibilidad para que no pasara desapercibida en caso de que a la gente le resultara de interés.

Answer (score 6):

Pues depende del uso que se le vaya a dar. Es una buena plataforma para docentes y lingüistas, y también le puede servir a estudiantes en general. El principal problema que me he encontrado es que desde la plataforma no puedes generar enlaces para incluir en este sitio de modo que todo el mundo pueda acceder a la información enlazada. Si desde Enclave RAE copias un enlace a la definición de una palabra, por ejemplo, el enlace se dirige a la plataforma de Enclave, y no al DLE, por lo que al final tenía que irme al DLE, copiar el enlace allí y pegarlo aquí para que todos tuvierais acceso al enlace. Y así con todo. Por lo demás, la mayor parte de las herramientas ofrecidas se pueden usar gratuitamente a través de los diferentes enlaces en la web de la RAE. Hay algunos recursos y opciones novedosas (aunque no muchos), que son las que pueden hacer merecer la pena pagar por el servicio.

Voy a pasar a describir con detalle el contenido de la plataforma, aunque existe un manual de uso en PDF que describe cada apartado, lo podéis encontrar [aquí](https://enclave.rae.es/pdfs/Guia_de_uso%20Enclave_RAE.pdf). Espero que esta información os sirva para decidiros si estáis con la duda. Y por supuesto, cualquier cosa que queráis preguntar la dejáis en comentarios para que pueda ir ampliando esta información, por si me he dejado alguna cosa en el tintero.

### Ficha de la palabra

Es una página con un resumen general y completo con información variada sobre una palabra. Muestra el artículo del DLE de la palabra, ejemplos de uso extraídos de diferentes corpus (aunque muy acortados), la primera aparición en textos seleccionados, una nube de palabras relacionadas (que entiendo que son las palabras más frecuentes que aparecen junto a la palabra seleccionada), un gráfico con la frecuencia de uso en textos seleccionados, la frecuencia de búsqueda en el DLE en el último año, y las entradas de la palabra en el mapa de diccionarios.

Opinión: casi toda la información aquí se puede obtener de herramientas gratuitas. Obviamente para la definición tenemos el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/). Los ejemplos de uso y la primera aparición en textos se pueden obtener entre el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) (o el CREA si es muy reciente), la [hemeroteca](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/index.vm) de la Biblioteca Nacional de España (o la específica de cada país si es un americanismo), o incluso [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams), de donde además se puede obtener una gráfica más detallada que la que aparece aquí. Sí es cierto que la gráfica de Enclave llega más atrás en el tiempo, con registros de hasta el siglo XI. La frecuencia de búsqueda en el diccionario coincide bastante con lo que se puede consultar en [Google Trends](https://trends.google.es/trends/?geo=ES). Y por último el mapa de diccionarios lo considero una herramienta incompleta en comparación con lo que se puede consultar en el [NTLLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle). Lo bueno es que aquí lo tienes todo de un vistazo, pero eso es todo, y además hay que ir con cuidado porque a veces falla. Por ejemplo, si se consulta el uso de *marrón* como color, que entró a formar parte del idioma a finales del siglo XIX, dice que el primer caso de uso es en el siglo XV, que no se corresponde con el uso actual. Casos así son fáciles de detectar, pero otros tal vez no tanto.

### Diccionario avanzado

Es un diccionario inverso, en el que puedes consultar definiciones que contengan la palabra de búsqueda. Para eso tenemos el [DIRAE](https://dirae.es/), solo que aquí se consulta sobre la última versión del diccionario. Personalmente es la parte que más me gusta, por el simple hecho de que se puede filtrar la búsqueda por facetas. Se puede buscar por categorías (adjetivo, adverbio, artículo, conjunción, contracción, expresión, formante, interjección, locución, onomatopeya, preposición, pronombre, sustantivo y verbo), pero también por género, geografía (si la palabra está marcada como de uso en un determinado lugar), grado, intención (afectivo, amenaza, benévolo, burla, despectivo, discriminatorio, enfático, favorable, festivo, insulto, irónico, peyorativo, ponderativo, positivo), idioma (del que proviene), nivel (culto, germanía, infantil, jergal, popular, rural, vulgar), número, origen (aquí se pueden consultar de golpe, por ejemplo, todas las marcas registradas que han llegado al diccionario), persona, registro, tecnicismo, tema, tipo, transición, uso (si tiene la marca de desuso) y valoración. Este filtro se puede ejecutar incluso si no hay término de búsqueda.

### Diccionarios

Se pueden consultar aquí los mismos diccionarios que hay en la web de la RAE, más el *Diccionario del estudiante*. No hay mucho que comentar aquí.

### Gramática

Consulta en el texto de la *Gramática* de la RAE. El texto sobre el que se busca es una versión reducida con respecto a la que se puede encontrar [aquí](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi), pero en este caso la búsqueda es más flexible, permitiendo buscar por varias palabras.

### Corpus avanzado

Permite buscar en el [Corpes XXI](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view), con textos que van desde 2001 hasta 2015. Al igual que la búsqueda avanzada, permite filtrar los resultados por facetas. Este caso son año, bloque (ficción o no), categoría, medio (escrito), origen (América, España, Filipinas, Guinea Ecuatorial), país, siglo (solo el XXI), soporte (Internet, libro, miscelánea, prensa), tema, tipología y zona. Las distintas facetas estarán o no disponibles según la búsqueda que se haga. Entiendo que este corpus está orientado al español actual, echando en falta esta misma potencia de búsqueda en corpus de referencia con textos más antiguos.

### Registro de consultas

Permite consultar la frecuencia de búsqueda de las palabras en el diccionario, al estilo de Google Trends como ya comenté antes, solo que aquí la búsqueda se hace más específica, pudiendo filtrar por país y por rango de fechas. Incluye un listado de palabras más consultadas en el diccionario y de palabras no incluidas en el diccionario. De este último listado, como curiosidad comentar que las palabras más buscadas no incluidas en el DLE incluyen en el top 10 palabras como *desescalada* y *coronavirus*, aunque suelen abundar los errores tipográficos como *resilencia*, *distopia*, *empatia*, *procastinar* y *oir*.

### Aula

No he consultado mucho esta sección, pero incluye una serie de cursos para estudiantes, clasificados por temas. Ejemplos de estos cursos son:

- Oraciones subordinadas sustantivas
- Uso de la tilde
- Uso de las letras
- Oraciones activas, pasivas, impersonales y medias
- El uso de los signos de puntuación: nivel avanzado

También incluye algunas obras, como «El Quijote en la historia de la lengua española», de José Manuel Blecua. Cada curso incluye el texto, ejemplos, ejercicios y un esquema/resumen.

### Taller lingüístico

**Verificador**

Es una curiosa utilidad que permite localizar errores de ortografía, gramaticales, léxicos y de estilo en una frase que le introduzcas. Lo estuve probando en su día y comprobé que introduce varios falsos positivos. Tampoco me da la sensación de que la detección de errores sea tan exhaustiva como se indica. Por ejemplo, he introducido la siguiente frase:

> Discusiones a parte, vamos a centrarnos en lo que realmente importa.

Y me dice que no se han detectado errores en el texto verificado.

**Palabras afines**

Busca palabras similares a la buscada en el DLE y en el *Diccionario del estudiante*, se puede considerar un diccionario de sinónimos, aunque no mucho porque las relaciones las establece según si una palabra enlaza con otra en el diccionario. Por ejemplo, si busco *romance* me encuentra *ladino* y *románico*, pero nada referente a la acepción de *romance* relativa a la relación amorosa.

**Anotador**

Permite introducir frases y te las analiza, permitiendo conocer de qué tipo es cada palabra, las unidades de análisis que hay, los nombres propios y otras clasificaciones.

**Conjugador**

Genera la conjugación de un verbo. Es la misma tabla que aparece al conjugar un verbo en el DLE.

### Consultas lingüísticas

En esta sección se pueden enviar consultas a la RAE referentes a la norma que regula el uso culto del español actual. Básicamente lo mismo que se hace puede hacer mediante el [Twitter de la RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma). Si se hacen otro tipo de consultas, como de corte histórico, de etimologías, etc., te dicen que se salen del ámbito del servicio. Lo bueno es que las consultas quedan registradas y las puedes consultar en cualquier momento, y además puedes buscar entre las miles de consultas realizadas por otros usuarios de la plataforma mediante palabras clave.

### Mi RAE

Es una carpeta personal donde añadir recursos, tanto ficheros que puedes subir (PDF, imagen o enlace) como recursos del aula. También se pueden crear libros a partir de dichas colecciones.